# Get value of matchNr with positive Match No in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using regular expression extractor with Match Number 2. The problem is when I use negative Match number in can refer matchNr variable but in case its positive I can't. Any one have idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If you have zero or positive number in `Match No` JMeter's [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) will return **not more than one** match, that's why you won't have this `xxx_matchNr` JMeter Variable.

As per Regular Expression Extractor documentation (the approach is applicable to all Post-Procesors)

> **Match No. (0 for Random)**
>
> Indicates which match to use. The regular expression may match multiple times.
>
> - Use a value of zero to indicate JMeter should choose a match at random.
> - A positive number N means to select the nth match.
> - Negative numbers are used in conjunction with the ForEach Controller - see below.

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)